# How to order multiple KML layers when they are added to a map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

I have two KML layers that load onto a map once clicked:

```
 <button id="button2" onclick="myFunctiongr(); loadKmlLayer(); initialize()">Submit</button>
 <script>

 src = "https://github.com/YourCity/hello-world/blob/readme-edits/"+name+".kmz?raw=true"}
 srca = " https://www.dropbox.com/s/5g0tytd1ur7my67/v7.kmz?dl=1"


 function initialize() {
   var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
   var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.50275896, -0.11535645),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)

    loadKmlLayer(src, map);
    loadKmlLayera(srca, map);
 }
```

This code works and loads both layers onto the map, however I would like the loadKmlLayer(src, map) to load first but it does not. Strangely if I refresh the page and try again it does! I cannot figure out why and how to make it load on top the first time.

The srca layer is larger than the src layer so I was thinking the size may be influencing it. Any help would be good!

(The 'LoadkmlLayer' & 'LoadkmlLayera' are functions defined elsewhere in my code. )

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use zIndex.  The layer with the lowest value of zIndex goes on the bottom, the layer with the largest value goes on the top.

**code snippet:**

```js
var name = "bcg";
var src = "https://github.com/YourCity/hello-world/blob/readme-edits/" + name + ".kmz?raw=true"
var srca = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/5g0tytd1ur7my67/v7.kmz?dl=1"


function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.50275896, -0.11535645),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)

  loadKmlLayer(src, map, 1);
  loadKmlLayer(srca, map, 0);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function loadKmlLayer(src, map, zIndex) {
  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: src,
    zIndex: zIndex,
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer, 'status_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML += "src=" + src + " status=" + ctaLayer.getStatus() + "<br>";
  })
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<button id="button2" onclick="myFunctiongr(); loadKmlLayer(); initialize()">Submit</button>
<div id="status"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```