# KmlLayer not always displayed

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml

On one of my webpages there a Google V3 API map upon which I add four KML layers.

Sometimes all four KML Layers will be displayed, but more often or not, only two or three layers are loaded. It is the last KML layer that loads less frequently. Refreshing the page will load more.

Here's my javascript

```
function initializeGoogleMap() 
{
    var mapOptions = {
            center: { lat: 45.325, lng: 14.254},
            zoom: 12,
            panControl: false,
            zoomControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            scaleControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            overviewMapControl: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
    
    new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:"https://www.virtualmountains.co.uk/Istria/PlacesOPOV1c.kml",map: map, preserveViewport: true});
    new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:"https://www.virtualmountains.co.uk/Istria/RoutesEdgeV1k.kml",map: map,preserveViewport: true});
    new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:"https://www.virtualmountains.co.uk/Istria/RoutesFillV1k.kml",map: map,preserveViewport: true});
    new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:"https://www.virtualmountains.co.uk/Istria/RoutesOPOV1n.kml",map: map,preserveViewport: true});
}
```

Presumably the KML files are to taking too long to download and are not available in time to be added to the map.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried adding code to check the [KmlStatus](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/kml#KmlLayer.getStatus) when the loading fails?

Comment: Related question: [issues with KML link to Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561979/issues-with-kml-link-to-google-maps-api) (has an example of how to check the KmlStatus)

Comment: Hi, this was a really useful suggestion, for what I'm seeing is that all four KML overlays are being added successfully, but not necessarily in the same order each time, and in the order I am requesting they be loaded.  So for example the forth layer (a thin yellow trace applied to some of the routes) is being covered by layers 2 or 3, depending on circumstances.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337507/kml-layers-rendering-order-google-maps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37472742/how-to-order-multiple-kml-layers-when-they-are-added-to-a-map

Comment: Also KmlLayer takes a [z-index](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/kml#KmlLayerOptions) parameter. Did you try that?

Comment: Learning that all KML layers were loading and it was just an ordering issue was useful, and then the final key to solving the problem, just use the z-index value as suggested by MrUpsidown, I didn't know there was this value.

Answer (score 0):

So for clarity, here's the final solution

```
function initializeGoogleMap() 
{
    var mapOptions = {
            center: { lat: 45.325, lng: 14.254},
            zoom: 12,
            panControl: false,
            zoomControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            scaleControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            overviewMapControl: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
        
    new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:"https://www.virtualmountains.co.uk/Istria/PlacesOPOV1c.kml", map: map, zIndex: 0, preserveViewport: true});
    new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:"https://www.virtualmountains.co.uk/Istria/RoutesEdgeV1k.kml", map: map, zIndex: 1, preserveViewport: true});
    new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:"https://www.virtualmountains.co.uk/Istria/RoutesFillV1k.kml", map: map, zIndex: 2, preserveViewport: true});
    new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:"https://www.virtualmountains.co.uk/Istria/RoutesOPOV1n.kml", map: map, zIndex: 3, preserveViewport: true});
    
}
```